# backbone model object in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

In my backbone model, I have an object like this

```
 {
   lunsize: "big",
   type: {mike: "who", james: "him"}
}
```

In my template when I do this

```
<% _.each(type, function(sip) { %>
<%= sip %>

<% }); %>
```

I get expected result which is `who` and `him`.

Wondering how I would loop over the entire model itself and not just the type field.

**PS:** I am using `toJSON()` to convert my model into an js object

Comment: "loop over the entire model" - Over the properties of the model? Using a `for-in` loop? Or over a collection of model items?

Comment: <% _.each(this.model.attributes, function(sip) { %>
<%= sip %>

<% }); %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `variable` setting of `template`.  This instructs underscore to create a function expecting a variable of the given name, rather than its default behavior of using `with` to change scope to the passed data object.

When creating your Backbone template, pass a variable name:

```
_.template(yourTemplate, null, {variable: "data"});
```

You can then access your data by that variable name inside the template:

```
<% _.each(data, function (val, key) { %>
  ...
<% }); %>
```

As `with` is quite slow, this has the added advantage of faster rendering.  From [the underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/):

> By default, template places the values from your data in the local scope via the with statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the variable setting. This can significantly improve the speed at which a template is able to render.

Comment: kkudos for the variable